# vue3 components library with sass

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I'm building a vue3 components library with vite library mode, which is fine; the thing is that it automatically generates the js files and a stylesheet compiled to `css` (I use `<style lang="scss" >` in my components;

I would like instead to make it build the `js` files and the styles still in `scss`;
the reason is that then in my apps that will use the components library, I can override sass variables defined in the components library